# Is there a 'slug' for assets?

Tags: assets, assetfilemodel

I'm trying to create a site with a gallery, and am investigating the possibility of getting Craft to treat an asset as an entry so I can display a detail page for an image without having to create an entry for it specifically.

I think it might do what I need, but I've fallen at the first hurdle whereby according to the documentation (unless I've missed it) assets don't have a slug. I could use ID, but the client will want keywords in the URL blah blah.

If I pull an asset and output {{ asset.slug }}, it does return what I'd want it to. The problem is, if I edit the title, that value isn't updated and there doesn't appear to be a way to get to it.

Is it possible to get to this somehow?

Comment: What happens if you change the filename instead of the title? Maybe `asset.slug` == filename?

Comment: It's definitely coming from the title as the filenames are totally different.

Answer (score 4):

Could you add your own field to use as a slug?

When you edit an Asset Source in Settings you get the `Field Layout` tab same as you do for Entries. You could maybe add something there and then combine this with a [Route](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#advanced-routing) somehow?

Comment: That was my backup plan, but it doesn't do the initial auto completion of the field that the slug field does which I like!

Comment: @AndyHarris You could use the [`onSaveAsset`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#assets-onSaveAsset) event, and do the auto-completion yourself.

Comment: @AndyHarris - Further to Victor's suggestion, if you take a look in `craft/app/helpers/ElementHelper.php`, there is a static method called `createSlug` which does all the hard work for you.

Comment: OK thanks chaps, I'll check that out - however, the slug I'm getting back must be coming from somewhere so I'm still keen to know if we can access that!